# Não usar chaves "{ }" em IF no PHP pode gerar problemas?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação, sintaxe

Geralmente para verificações que modificam apenas uma linha eu tenho evitado o uso de chaves, pois o PHP aceita esse método, porem raramente vejo códigos de outros programadores assim... Exemplos

Meu método

```
if($thumb->SaveInDB('imagens','img'))
    $ok = true;
else
    $ok = false;
```

Método normal

```
if($thumb->SaveInDB('imagens','img'))
{
    $ok = true;
}
else
{
    $ok = false;
}
```

Faz alguma diferença usar as chaves "{ }" nesses casos? existe a possibilidade do php retornar erro ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Dá na mesma. Eu utilizo chaves por questão de organização.

Comment: as respostas do @DiegoVieira, bfavaretto e gpupo se complementam bem... acredito que seria bom se alguém incluísse em sua resposta referencia as outras para deixar a resposta bem completa :D

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162974/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-usos-do-foreach-no-php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Na verdade o `IF` sem chaves só pode ser usado apenas na execução de um comando e quando for uma cadeia de comandos você utiliza as chaves para indicar que, no instante `{` até o termino `}` execute. Veja os exemplos abaixo.

A mesma lógia aplica-se à linguagens como PHP, Javascript, Typescript e C#.

Isto irá funcionar!

***PHP***

```
if($meuVar == true)
   echo 'verdadeiro';
else
   echo 'falso';

if($meuVar == true)
{
   echo "Sim";
   echo "<br> É verdadeiro";
}
else
   echo "Não <br> É verdadeiro";
```

Isto NÃO irá funcionar!

***PHP***

```
if($meuVar == true)
   echo 'Sim';
   echo '<br> é Verdadeiro';
else
   echo 'Não';
   echo '<br> é Verdadeiro';
```

Eu mesmo utilizo em meus códigos quando irei executar apenas um comando, esse método também funciona em outras linguagens tal como `C#`

Isso também vale para outros comandos, exemplos abaixo.

***PHP***

```
for($i == 0; $i < 10; $i++)
   echo $i;

while($i < 10)
   echo $i++;

foreach($items as $item)
   echo $item->meuCampo;
```

Vou deixar uma demo do `for` e o `while` em ação. **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/oLYR5z)**

Comment: Então na verdade as `{ }` só servem para garantir que temos uma cadeia de execuções, em outras palavras não existe possibilidade de erros quando não existe uma cadeia... seria mais ou menos isso?

Comment: se o comando for utilizado de forma correta ele não irá mostrar erros, mas lembre-se, apenas na execução de um comando, no exemplo do @bfavaretto ele mostra que pode ocorrer erro de lógica.

Answer (score 17):

Isso é um debate polêmico em diversas linguagens, não apenas PHP. Não existe uma resposta correta. Em última instância é uma questão de estilo e não irá gerar problemas *se todos os cuidados necessários forem tomados*.

Muita gente recomenda sempre usar as chaves para evitar problemas durante a manutenção do código. Se você omite as chaves e em outro momento alguém (até mesmo você) decide incluir uma segunda instrução no corpo do `if` ou do `else`, pode esquecer de adicionar as chaves, e gerar um erro de sintaxe:

```
if($foo == 1) 
   echo 'aaaa';
   echo 'bbbb'; // erro de sintaxe
else
   echo 'cccc';
```

Ou, pior ainda, um erro de lógica que pode passar despercebido:

```
if($foo == 2) 
   echo 'aaaa';
else
   echo 'bbbb';
   echo 'cccc'; // executa incondicionalmente!!!
```

Answer (score 6):

Como todas as respostas disseram, você só pode usar UM comando depois de um if sem chaves

Mas, se você não gosta das chaves, tem outra opção:

```
if($algumacoisa) :
    echo 'foo';
    echo 'bar';
endif;
```

O mesmo pra while, for e foreach, só que o final é trocado pra o respectivo nome com "end" anteriormente.

**[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/fEjBPT)**

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de executar,(*`IF` sem chaves só pode ser usado apenas na execução de um comando*) você terá um problema de escrita e organização, por isso é recomendado que você siga o que foi decidido na [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

**5.1. if, elseif, else**

> An if structure looks like the following. Note the placement of
>   parentheses, spaces, and braces; and that else and elseif are on the
>   same line as the closing brace from the earlier body.

```
<?php
if ($expr1) {
    // if body
} elseif ($expr2) {
    // elseif body
} else {
    // else body;
}
```

> The keyword elseif SHOULD be used instead of else if so that all
>   control keywords look like single words.

Comment: Observação. Trocaria `o que foi decidido na PSR-2` por `a recomendação do PSR-2`

Answer (score 1):

Quando você omitir as chaves você só vai tratar a próxima instrução como o corpo da condição:

```
if ($x) echo 'foo'; 
é o mesmo que 

if ($x) {echo 'foo'; } 
mas lembre-se que 

if ($x) 
   echo 'foo'; 
   echo 'bar';
```

imprime sempre "bar"

PHP trata tudo em {} como uma única expressão "agrupados".

O mesmo vale para as outras instruções de controle (foreach e assim por diante)

Answer (score -2):

Colegas
no suporte ja deparei com erros devido as faltas de aspas no if

codigo.....

```
if(true)
    function x();
    function Y();
```

executa `function y()` como parte do código sem levar em consideração o `if` 
esse erro num código não muito legível me fez gastar um dia e meio e provoca erros aleatórios difíceis de encontrar