# No PHP o correto é else if ou elseif?

Tags: php, if, sintaxe, condição

No PHP, o correto é `else if` ou `elseif`? Qual a diferença entre eles?

A linguagem permite escrever tudo junto e separado, e aparentemente os resultados são idênticos

Comment: Entendi sua questão. Separei 2 referências da questão marcada como duplicata: [**Ref 1**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57791/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-else-e-elseif#comment119144_57804), [**Ref 2**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57799/13412).

Comment: [A documentação explica bem](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php), mas resumindo, "else if" não compila no uso de sentenças que usam dois pontos (:).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Como nenhuma das respostas falou disso, achei melhor incluir outra. Já foi dito, e é verdade, que para fins práticos `elseif` e `else if` são equivalentes (exceto na sintaxe com `if():`/ `endif;`, que não permite `else if` separado). Mas por quê?

Provavelmente você já sabe que [é possível omitir as chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25184/n%C3%A3o-usar-chaves-em-if-no-php-pode-gerar-problemas) após um `if` ou `else` se depois dele só vier uma linha:

```
if($condicao)
    echo 'esta linha só executa se passar na condição';
    echo 'esta linha SEMPRE EXECUTA';
```

ou

```
if($condicao)
    echo 'esta linha só executa se passar na condição';
else
    echo 'esta linha só executa SE NÃO PASSAR na condição';
    echo 'esta linha SEMPRE EXECUTA';
```

Quando você usa `else if`, separados, o que tem é um `else` que não é seguido de chaves, com um `if` dentro.

Um exemplo assim:

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} else if ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
```

Na verdade são dois [`if`s aninhados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57815), assim:

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} else 
    if ($a == $b) {
        echo "a is equal to b";
    } else {
        echo "a is smaller than b";
    }
```

Comment: agora ficou bem claro p/ mim

Answer (score 8):

Essencialmente é a mesma coisa. As duas sintaxes são aceitas na maioria dos casos. A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) mostra uma situação em que não pode mas é algo que raramente um programador PHP  usa. Na sintaxe que usa o `:` e `endif` como delimitadores do bloco do `if` não aceita o uso do `else if`.

Isto pode ser visto aqui:

```
if (true) 
    echo "true";
elseif (false)
    echo "false";
echo "\n";
if (true) 
    echo "true";
else if (false)
    echo "false";
echo "\n";
if (true):
    echo "true";
elseif (false):
    echo "false";
endif;
echo "\n";
if (true):
    echo "true";
else if (false): //isto não compilará
    echo "false";
endif;
echo "\n";
if (true) {
    echo "true";
} elseif (false) {
    echo "false";
}
echo "\n";
if (true) {
    echo "true";
} else if (false) {
    echo "false";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/8l8qMv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cbjtxbtf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/IfElseIf.php).

Answer (score 8):

Segundo o [manual online do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php), só são considerados iguais se usados com chaves após a condição.
Se forem usadas com `:` (sem chaves), então separar `else if` vai gerar um erro.

No site do manual é possível encontrar:

> No PHP, você pode escrever 'else if' (em duas palavras) que o
>   comportamento será idêntico a 'elseif' (em uma única palavra).

*Exemplo adaptado por mim:*

```
<?php
/* Escritos juntos: */
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}

/* Escritos separados: */
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} else if ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

Ainda no site do manual, é afirmado que há uma única diferença... (além da diferença sintática, *-> que para o programador é algo indiferente <-* esta parte é minha):

> Nota: Note que elseif e else if só serão considerados exatamente
>   iguais se usados com chaves como no exemplo abaixo. Quando usando com
>   dois pontos (:) para definir as condições if/elseif, você não pode
>   separar else if em duas palavras, ou o PHP irá falhar com um erro de
>   interpretação.

```
<?php

/* Incorrect Method: */
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
else if($a == $b): // Will not compile.
    echo "The above line causes a parse error.";
endif;


/* Correct Method: */
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
elseif($a == $b): // Note the combination of the words.
    echo $a." equals ".$b;
else:
    echo $a." is neither greater than or equal to ".$b;
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Quando você fala de diferença sintática, quer dizer **[isto](http://ideone.com/1B46XQ)**?

Comment: Não foi isso. Me referia à diferença sintática entre o `else if` e o `elseif`... essa diferença só pode ser notada pelo parser do PHP no seu processo interno de parse.

Comment: É, mas acho que isso não estava claro pro AP ainda. Postei uma resposta tratando do assunto.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o [Manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php), se você utilizar as chaves `{}` o resultado é exatamente o mesmo.

De acordo com a recomendação de padronização para PHP atual, [PSR 12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#51-if-elseif-else): a palavra-chave `elseif` deveria/poderia (should) ser usada em vez de `else if` para que todas as palavras-chave de controle pareçam palavras únicas. Mas não é regra, é sugestão.

Particularmente, como dá na mesma, eu gosto de usar `else if` por comodidade, pois além do **PHP** eu também codifico em **nodeJS** e **C#** e ambas aceitam só `else if`. Assim eu padronizo meus códigos.