# Montar "if"s de acordo com critérios

Tags: php, mysql, if

Estou com um dúvida na condição que estou querendo colocar no meu sistema. No caso o site vai verificar se o "Paid" está com o resultado 1; se tiver 1, ele vai colocar "Entregue", mas se tiver 0 ele fica "Pendente", agora se o valor ficar *refunded* era para ele ficar "Rembolsado" e tirar o "Entregue" ou "Pendente", como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código:

```
<?php if($transaction->paid == 1): ?>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Entregue</span></td>
<?php else: ?>
    <td><span class="badge badge-warning">Pendente</span>/td>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($transaction->status == refunded): ?>
    <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Rembolsado</span></td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre else e elseif?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57791/3774)

Comment: Relacionada: [No PHP o correto é else if ou elseif?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57891/3774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro coloque a condição do `status` e um `else` onde terá outro `if` para a condição do `paid`:

```
<?php if($transaction->status == refunded): ?>
<td><span class="badge badge-danger">Rembolsado</span></td>
<?php else: ?>
   <?php if($transaction->paid == 1): ?>
<td><span class="badge badge-success">Entregue</span></td>
   <?php else: ?>
<td><span class="badge badge-warning">Pendente</span></td>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: vlw, me ajudou aqui

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente tem um erro conceitual no sistema, mas já que está assim pode resolver desta forma (espero ter entendido e tenha sido colocado corretamente os critérios):

```
<?php if($transaction->status == "refunded"): ?> //isto provavelmente está errado, mas foi colocado errado, não sei qual deva ser o certo
    <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Rembolsado</span></td>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($transaction->paid == 1): ?>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Entregue</span></td>
    <?php else: ?>
        <td><span class="badge badge-warning">Pendente</span></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/IfTemplate.php).

Desta forma se o `status` é `refunded` ele assume que isso é que importa, caso contrário, ele verificará o `paid`. Considerei que o reembolso tem prioridade de acordo com a descrição. Isto chama-se `if` aninhado.