# Qual a diferença entre os usos do foreach no php?

Tags: php, foreach

Qual a diferença entre esses dois meios de se usar o `foreach` no php? Seria um mais especial do que o outro, trazendo alguma vantagem por exemplo?

Método 1:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    #do something 
}
```

Método 2:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value): 
  #do something 
endforeach;
```

Existem outras variações como essa para o `foreach` ou para outras instruções parecidas no php?

Comment: pessoalmente eu uso assim: quando o bloco é pequeno o suficiente pra se ver começo e fim na mesma tela ou quando não são muitos blocos um dentro do outro, uso `{}`. Quando o bloco é longo o suficiente pra vc ter que rolar a tela, quando tem muito HTML no meio ou quando são tantos if/else/foreach/for/while juntos que fica aquele rabo imenso de `}` no final eu prefiro `endif; endforeach; ` etc, porque fica fácil visualizar onde cada um acaba.

Comment: Seguindo essa lógica também sei que se estou sendo usando muito a segunda opção é porque provavelmente tem um jeito mais inteligente/curto de fazer o que eu quero e eu preciso refatorar. Meu eu do futuro sempre agradece quando tem que voltar ali.

Comment: relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25184/n%C3%A3o-usar-chaves-em-if-no-php-pode-gerar-problemas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando as respostas existentes e para evitar falar mais do mesmo, dentro desse contexto entra também os padrões de código.

Existem padrões amplamente aceitos por comunidades PHP no mundo todo.

<sub>*Não quer dizer que todos aceitam. Alguns refutam ou ignoram.</sub>

Um exemplo é os padrões do http://www.php-fig.org/

Podemos mencionar o PSR-2.

Tudo que é "sintaxe alternativa" ou "aliases" sempre fica de fora dos padrões de código. No caso do PSR-2, o padrão propõe sempre usar chaves `{}` para abertura e fechamento de estruturas de controle de fluxo e declaração de funções e classes.

Exemplo

```
class Foo
{

}
```

Existem certas regras minuciosas, como exemplo, isso é considerado "errado"

```
class Foo 
{

}
```

Visualmente parece o mesmo que o primeiro, mas note que há um espaço antes de quebrar a abertura de `{`. IDEs em modo restrito podem emitir um aviso de correção.

Para o PHP, é indiferente:

```
class Foo {

}

class Foo{}
```

A questão é mais visual e otimização para IDEs e compiladores terceiros e, obviamente, organização/padronização de escrita.

Houve uma época que muitos omitiam os cholchetes em instruções de 1 linha e inclusive foi amplamente difundido e virou padrão em muitas documentações:

```
if(instrução)
    //faz isso

//outro código
```

Outra forma

```
if(instrução)
    //faz isso
else
    //faz aquilo
```

Atualmente a recomendação é evitar suprimir os colchetes pois pode trazer confusão. NO PSR-2, pede para que mesmo quando há somente 1 linha, sempre escrever o colchete.

```
if (instrução) {
    //faz isso
} else {
    //faz aquilo
}
```

Repare também que há detalhes nesse último exemplo:

- Logo após o if há um espaço.

- Não há espaços nos parênteses.

- Logo após fechar o parêntese há um espaço

É importante manter esse padrão pois muitas plataformas adotam o PSR-2 e validam os códigos dentro desses padrões. Você pode ter problemas em ter que adaptar centenas de milhares de códigos seguindo um outro padrão desconhecido ou inventando um próprio que não seja igual ao PSR.

Há certas tolerâncias para sintaxes alternativas como o uso dessa sintaxe

```
echo (condição)? 'ok': 'ng';
```

Aqui mencionei o if, porém aplica-se o mesmo as outras estruturas de controle de fluxo

```
foreach () {

}

while () {

}

for () {

}
```

Note que os exemplos acima são baseados nas regras do PSR. Normas de padrão de código podem variar dependendo da plataforma que utiliza.

Um exemplo, o Wordpress permite algo assim `if ( condition ) {`

Esse espaço na condição não é permitido outras plataformas que não o toleram, como o validador de sintaxes do PrestaShop, por exemplo.

Mas o Wordpress permite escrever dessa forma `if (condition) {`.

Portanto, é sempre melhor seguir o que é mais amplamente aceito pois um código que você escreve para um plataforma pode ser aceito com mais facilidade numa plataforma terceira.

Um exemplo usando o próprio PrestaShop, essa plataforma, até 2 anos atrás, obrigava a supressão das chaves em instruções de uma linha:

```
if ()
    //uma linha
```

Porém, recentemente mudaram esse padrão. Atualmente não é permitido. Quem usava o padrão PSR-2 se deu bem pois não teve trabalho em mudar nada. O PrestaShop adotou o PSR-2 e obriga o seu uso.

O mesmo pode acontecer com outras plataformas como o Wordpress, Magento, etc.

*<sub>Citei essas plataformas como exemplo por serem populares.</sub>

Ainda assim há aqueles que se recusam a usar os padrões do php-fig.org. Quanto a isso não podemos fazer nada pois esse site é totalmente independente do PHP e não é uma espécie de lei onde todos são obrigados a seguir.

Contudo, um fato que ninguém pode negar é que esses padrões do PHP-fig são amplamente aceitos no mundo inteiro. Você pode estar no Afeganistão, no México, no Brasil, no Vietnã ou na Groelândia e encontrará programadores PHP seguindo esse padrão. Não é algo localizado onde pessoas de um país seguem e o resto do mundo desconhece.

Aqui evitei comentar sobre padrões de identação e quebra de linha em condicionais longas pois o foco da pergunta é específico sobre o uso de sintaxe alternativa as chaves `{}`.

Answer (score 8):

Eu já tinha visto isso antes, mas pesquisei só pra confirmar. Não há nenhuma diferença, tecnicamente falando.

O segundo método é mais utilizado quando há códigos html no meio, por exemplo:

```
<?php
    $arr = blah();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value):
?>
<h1>Hello .. <?php echo $value; ?></h1>
mais código html aqui...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Fica mais elegante do que isso:

```
<?php
    $arr = blah();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
?>
<h1>Hello .. <?php echo $value; ?></h1>
mais código html aqui...
<?php } ?>
```

Existem vários outros.. `if/endif`; `switch/endswitch`; `for/endfor`. Pode conferir a lista [no manual do php](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 7):

Não há nenhuma diferença em termos de funcionamento, internamente ambas se transformarão no mesmo ao serem executadas.

Sua razão de ser é mera opção, ao que tudo indica, para melhor legibilidade em contextos diferentes. Tem situações em que a indentação fica confusa, especialmente quando misturado com blocos HTML, como já disse o colega @Kirito94, mas isso só dá para analisar caso a caso.

Como diz o próprio manual do PHP:

> O PHP oferece uma sintaxe alternativa para algumas estruturas de controle; a saber, if, while, for, foreach, e switch. Em cada caso, basicamente a sintaxe alternativa é trocar a chave de abertura por dois pontos (:) e a chave de fechamento por endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, ou endswitch;, respectivamente.

Ainda, no manual, fica claro que funciona nos blocos de `else` e `elseif`

```
<?php
if ($a == 5):
    echo "a equals 5";
    echo "...";
elseif ($a == 6):
    echo "a equals 6";
    echo "!!!";
else:
    echo "a is neither 5 nor 6";
endif;
?>
```

Mais detalhes no link:

**[Sintaxe Alternativa para estruturas de controle](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**.

Comment: Só pra constar, eu uso sempre `{` e `}`, dependendo do seu grau de organização, não atrapalha a legibilidade em nada. Inclusive, da forma que eu uso, ficaria mais confuso com fechamento "por extenso". Precisa ver o contexto de cada um, não acredito que neste caso exista uma regra possível de determinar qual o melhor. Só depende do estilo de cada um.

Comment: Obrigado por citar a documentação, não tinha visto muito o uso disso para saber que não se usava apenas com o `foreach `.

Comment: @Florida entendo, é que quando você vê pela primeira vez num código real, dá a impressão que é coisa do foreach mesmo. Só coloquei o comment na sua pergunta antes de responder para adiantar o assunto, enquanto formatava a resposta.