# Quando se usar o IF com ENDIF?

Tags: php, if

Em quais circunstancias se deve usar o:

```
IF(CONDICAO) :

ELSE:

ENDIF;
```

Comment: Ele funciona igual as chaves, `{}`.

Comment: Sintaxe Alternativa para estruturas de controle  https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#control-structures.alternative-syntax

Comment: Então é apenas uma forma diferente de se trabalhar com o if?

Comment: exato, apenas uma sintaxe alternativa

Comment: Entendi, vlw brother.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente utiliza-se as chaves { } para delimitar o escopo de um determinado bloco de código.

```
<?php
    //sintaxe normal
    if (expressão) {
       //código php
    }

    //sintaxe alternativa, repare no uso dos : e da palavra endif
    if (expressão) :
       //codigo php
    endif
?>
```

**Estruturas de Controles Alternativa**

Estruturas de controle, como if, for, foreach, e while também podem ser escritas de um jeito simplificado. Aqui vai um exemplo usando foreach:

```
<ul>

<?php foreach($afazeres as $item): ?>

<li><?=$item?></li>

<?php endforeach ?>

</ul>
```

Note que não há chaves. Ao invés disto, a chave do final foi trocada por um endforeach. Cada estrutura listada acima tem uma sintaxe de fechamento similar: endif, endfor, endforeach, e endwhile

Note também que no lugar de usar um ponto e vírgula para cada estrutura (exceta a última), há o sinal de dois pontos. Isto é importante!

Outro exemplo, usando if/elseif/else. Note os dois pontos:

```
<?php if ($username == 'Adri Silva'): ?>

   <h3>Oi Adri Silva</h3>

<?php elseif ($username == 'Leo'): ?>

   <h3>Oi Leo</h3>

<?php else: ?>

   <h3>Oi usuário desconhecido</h3>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**OU**

```
<?php 

if ($username == 'Adri Silva'):

   echo "Oi Adri Silva";

elseif ($username == 'Leo'):

   echo "Oi Leo";

else:

   echo "Oi usuário desconhecido";

endif; 

?>
```

[Sintaxe Alternativa para estruturas de controle](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#control-structures.alternative-syntax)

> Ai você pode se perguntar: existe alguma diferença, performance e coisa e tal? Esse [**post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162974/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-usos-do-foreach-no-php/162977#162977) aborda essa questão

Answer (score -2):

Quando se quer comparar algo, relações.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]